# Question regarding mass hanging from center edge of rotating disc

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics

So, say you have a free to rotate disc, assuming no external torques, and you have a spool, radius 7.93 mm, attached to its centre.

[image]

Say the spool has a string attached to a point on its edge and the string supports a mass, 14.7 g.

Now you wind up the string around the spool and allow the mass to fall, accelerating at linear acceleration $a_l$ and causing the disc to rotate at angular acceleration 0.66 rad/s.

How is the angular acceleration of the disc related to linear acceleration of the mass? And how would I use the angular acceleration to find the $a_l$? In other words by what equation would I be able to find the $a_l$ from the angular acceleration of the disc?

Does it have something to do with the fact that each time the spool rotates one revolution, its position has changed by $2\pi r$, so therefore, the amount of string fed out would equal $2\pi r$?

If so, how would I convert that information into an equation relating the two accelerations?

Comment: Can you provide a diagram for your question? It will help draw a quantitative answer.

Comment: I have revised my question and added some new information to make it more understandable. Please give me another try.

Answer (score 1):

You know the string length is constant so a small change in angle $\Delta\theta$ on the pulley yields what change in height $y$ of the mass?

once you have $\Delta y = K \Delta \theta$ you can differential twice to get

$$ \frac{{\rm d} y}{{\rm d}t} = K \frac{{\rm d} \theta}{{\rm d}t} 
\\ \frac{{\rm d}^2 y}{{\rm d}t^2} = K \frac{{\rm d}^2 \theta}{{\rm d}t^2}  $$

since coefficient (gearing) $K$ you come up with is constant with time. The above is simply $a = K \alpha$ relating the linear to the angular acceleration.